# What libraries use design patterns implemented with compile-time metaprogramming techniques?

Tags: c++, design-patterns, templates, metaprogramming, compile-time

Does anybody know of any libraries that use design patterns that are implemented using compile-time techniques e.g. template metaprogramming? I know that Loki implements a few but I need to find other libraries.

Comment: Can you enumerate the design patterns you find in Loki that you are interested in?

Comment: well. I'm interested in all of them... I'm writing a report on design patterns and their compile-time implementations i.e. the compiler knows exactly which classes to use for compilation (I dont know if the qusetion is clear). The ones in Loki that I can remember off the top of my head are singleton, abstract factory and visitor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you are asking for libraries that help to use design pattern more that libraries using design patterns, isn't it?

There are some in Boost but not too much, like Flyweight  - Design pattern to manage large quantities of highly redundant objects.

The not yet released but accepted library Boost.Factory and the rejected library Boost.Singleton

There are also some libraries that implements C++ idioms as Boost.Pimpl (on the review schedule), Scope Exit (accepted), Memoizer.

Comment: boost::iterator_Facade is another big one (at least for me)

Comment: I'm doing research on the design patterns so it is more on the implementation of the design patterns but libraries that help you use them or that use them in their own implementation is fine

Comment: Wow, the answer was accepted and no one up voted. Is this possible?

Answer (score 6):

[Boost.Spirit](http://boost-spirit.com/home/) is a pretty big one.

Comment: which patterns can be/are used by it?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what design pattern you are interested in. There are some like "Active Object" and Dispose that would have a hard time being implemented at compile time.

"interpreter" pattern -> boost.ublas and blitz++ both use "expression templates"

"bridge" pattern -> Every standard container takes an "allocator" argument (most of Loki is bridge patterns as well)

"strategy" pattern -> STL template functions choose the best implementation based on the argument types

The only difference in all of these is that the evaluation of the pattern happens when the compiler runs, rather then when the executable runs. So all you need is to adjust your thinking slightly: The templates are the program, and the "C++ compiler" runs and interprets this program. The output of this template program is an object file ready for linking. In other words, your template code's runtime is precisley when your compiler is running. C++ templates are a turing complete functional language, just like lisp or XSLT.

In fact the very first template metaprogram in 1993 had as its output not an executable, but a series of compiler errors that printed the fibonacii sequence or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

Some libraries that use expression templates: ublas, blitz, matrix template Library, ftensor, or Google C++ template matrix to find even more.

by the way, ftensor is really slick http://www.gps.caltech.edu/~walter/FTensor/FTensor.pdf.

Answer (score 0):

Doen almal GPG hier?

Any case those implemented in Loki:
 - Factory Abstract
 - Factory
 - Singleton
 - Visitor
 - Command

In boost  Flyweight

In STL you have iterators, and adapters, although I'm pretty sure they don't count
due to being  being compile-time?

The original specification is somewhat vague.

Make sure that you do not confuse generic programming (template-based implementations) with other compile-time techniques.

Anyone have a clue as to what the above question means?